# Database Query Locator vs Simple Query

Tags: apex, database

I want to know what is the difference between Database.QueryLocator() and simple SOQL Query i.e.

```
List<Inventory__c> invent = [Select Id,Quantity__c,AccountId__c,Name,Expiry_Date__c From Inventory__c];
```

And

```
Database.getQueryLocator([Select Id,Quantity__c,AccountId__c,Name,Expiry_Date__c From Inventory__c]);
```

I want to know what is QueryLocator class in Apex.. I went through this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_batch.htm#apex_methods_system_database_batch) but cannot understand its structure..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Database.QueryLocator :](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm)  when used the governor limit for the total number of records retrieved by SOQL queries is bypassed. For example, a batch Apex job for the Account object can return a QueryLocator for all account records (**up to 50 million records**) in an org. Another example is a sharing recalculation for the Contact object that returns a QueryLocator for all account records in an org.

> For the regular query you do have a [limit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) of 50,000 rows per
>   transaction

Answer (score 23):

Before we proceed about [QueryLocator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_batch.htm#apex_methods_system_database_batch) class and let's see the limits of it.

I wrote a sample debug statement to see the limits of the number of rows returned by query locator and normal square bracket [] query

```
System.debug(Limits.getLimitQueryLocatorRows()); // 10000
System.debug(Limits.getLimitQueryRows()); //50000
```

> So in a Synchronous transaction when you use
> Database.getQueryLocator(10,000) you get less number of rows than normal
> [] Square bracket query(50,000).

Now, let's see how to use `QueryLocator`. `QueryLocator` is nothing but a query cursor. Which is pretty useless on its own, but it can help us get an [**Iterator**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_database_querylocatoriterator.htm#apex_class_database_querylocatoriterator). And that iterator can help us iterating through that set of records.

```
Database.QueryLocator ql = Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT id FROM Account ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 10000]);

Database.QueryLocatorIterator iterator = ql.iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Account acc = (Account) iterator.next();
    //Work on your list
   
}
```

Bit tedious isn't it? Such a pain....

Why would you want to use `QueryLocator` instead of a normal square bracket query?

The answer lies in **HEAP**. As you can see from the code above, the Iterator can only get 1 record at a time, thus taking less memory, where as the SOQL [] gets the big `List` which can sometimes cause `HeapLimitExceeded` exception. Thus if you are querying large number of fields and processing them and have concern that you can reach heap limitations, it's better to use `QueryLocator` instead of normal SOQL.